# assign part of a scalar to another variable using regular expressions

Tags: regex, perl

I've got a column of scalars (assigned to variable $contig) that all look about like this:

```
c46360_g1_i1_resultsMinus3HEditlen=341
```

I want to take the first part (c46360_g1_i1) and assign that to a new variable and print it. Basically chop off the "_resultsMinus3HEditlen=341" on all the scalars in that column. The numbers after the c, the g, and the i are all different.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
while ( my $line = <RESULTS> ) {
    chomp $line;
    my @column = split( /[\s|]/, $line );
    my $goID = $column[4];
    my $contig = $column[0];
    $goHash{$contig} = $goID;
    print $contig, "\t", $goID, "\n";
}
```

Comment: What language is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my ($contig_prefix) = $contig =~ /^(c[0-9]+_g[0-9]+_i[0-9]+)/;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample code to do what you expect :

```
perl -E '
    my $var = "c46360_g1_i1_resultsMinus3HEditlen=341";
    (my $newvar = $var) =~ s/_resultsMinus3HEditlen=\d+//;
    say $newvar
'
```